# C# SSO hashing migrated to PHP

Tags: c#, php, pbkdf2

I'm working on an SSO implementation in PHP that authenticates to a system written in C#. Here's some pseudo code to demonstrate:

```
$token = "MqsXexqpYRUNAHR_lHkPRic1g1BYhH6bFNVPagEkuaL8Mf80l_tOirhThQYIbfWYErgu4bDwl-7brVhXTWnJNQ2";
$id = "bob@company.com";
$ssokey = "7MpszrQpO95p7H";
$idAndKey = $id . $ssokey;
$salt = base64_decode(substr($token, 0, -1));
$hashed = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $idAndKey, mb_convert_encoding($salt, 'UTF-16LE'), 1000, 24, false);
$data = base64_encode($hashed);
```

This outputs: `NWZiMTBhZmNhNTlmYzMxMTEzMThhZmVl`

Here's the C# version from the system with which I'm integrating:

```
var token = "MqsXexqpYRUNAHR_lHkPRic1g1BYhH6bFNVPagEkuaL8Mf80l_tOirhThQYIbfWYErgu4bDwl-7brVhXTWnJNQ2";
var id = "bob@company.com";
var ssokey = "7MpszrQpO95p7H";
string idAndKey = id + ssokey;
var salt = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(token);
var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(idAndKey, salt) {IterationCount = 1000};
var key = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(pbkdf2.GetBytes(24)); 
Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
```

This outputs: `aE1k9-djZ66WbUATqdHbWyJzskMI5ABS0`

I cannot figure out how to get my PHP code to do the same thing. I have a feeling it is in the `salt` generation.

I've tried to translate the C# `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode` function to PHP like so:

```
function UrlTokenDecode($token) {
    $numPadChars = substr($token, -1);

    // add the padded count to the end
    $salt = substr($token, 0, -1) . $numPadChars;

    // Transform the "-" to "+", and "*" to "/"
    $salt = str_replace('-', '+', str_replace('*', '/', $salt));

    // base64_decode
    $salt = base64_decode($salt);

    return $salt;
}
```

That didn't get me to where I needed to go. Halp!

This is for Absorb LMS. Documentation of their methods are here: https://support.absorblms.com/hc/en-us/articles/222446647-Incoming-Absorb-Single-Sign-On#Methods

Thanks!

Comment: One thing is `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` uses sha1 as hash function, not sha256.

Comment: Thank you! The Absorb docs specifically stated sha256, so that threw me off. I've updated my code, but still not getting the desired results. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know php at all, but still can help I think. First, as stated in my comment, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in C# uses SHA1 as hash function, not SHA256, doesn't matter what your documentation says.

Next, `UrlTokenDecode` (and `Encode`) is quite strange thing I rarely seen in practice. It converts regular base64 to "url safe" version as follows:

- replaces '+' with '-'
- replaces '/' with '_'
- removes padding ('==' at the end) and appends length of removed padding **as a number** as last character (if there were no padding - it still appends "0"). This step doesn't make any sense to me, but it's how it works.

So to replicate you need to `base64_encode`, replace, remove padding, and then add padding length as character. So if your base64 string ended with `==` - you remove that and add "2" at the end. If there was no padding - you add "0".

So to decode that string you need to make back replacement, then remove last character and add that much '=' to the end as indicated by that character.

So string

```
MqsXexqpYRUNAHR_lHkPRic1g1BYhH6bFNVPagEkuaL8Mf80l_tOirhThQYIbfWYErgu4bDwl-7brVhXTWnJNQ2
```

In normal base64 is
  MqsXexqpYRUNAHR/lHkPRic1g1BYhH6bFNVPagEkuaL8Mf80l/tOirhThQYIbfWYErgu4bDwl+7brVhXTWnJNQ==

Then, I have no idea why you do that

```
mb_convert_encoding($salt, 'UTF-16LE')
```

Just remove it (though as I don't know php - there might be some reason you are doing that, but I just cannot imagine which, so take care).

Then as other answer states - the last argument to hash_pbkdf2() should be true.

After making this changes your code will work (I used token already converted to normal base64 string):

```
$token = "MqsXexqpYRUNAHR/lHkPRic1g1BYhH6bFNVPagEkuaL8Mf80l/tOirhThQYIbfWYErgu4bDwl+7brVhXTWnJNQ==";
$id = "bob@company.com";
$ssokey = "7MpszrQpO95p7H";
$idAndKey = $id . $ssokey;
$salt = base64_decode($token);
$hashed = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $idAndKey, $salt, 1000, 24, true);
$data = base64_encode($hashed);
echo $data;
```

produces expected answer (in normal base64 - you need to "url encode" it to get exact match).

Comment: This is fantastic. Between your answer and @Sammitch (I wish I could mark both as correct), I'm now getting the correct output. The sha1 was the key to the puzzle, but properly encoding/decoding (thought I was already) made the difference.

Comment: Ugh that thing with the padding at the end of the base64 is *super* dumb. At least in PHP you can just drop that "padding" char prior to the decoding with no ill effect. I've added some sassy functions to my answer that should be useful.

Comment: @Sammitch yeah, I didn't even know such method existsed until this question. Good that almost noone actually uses that strange "safe" base64 anyway.

Comment: URL-safe base64 is actually starting to creep in fairly often, primarily in JWT implementations. The odd part is tacking on a number for padding rather than just dropping it. If your base64 decode function *requires* padding you can easily just pad the string to a multiple of 4. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well sure, url safe base64 is fine, but this particular implementation is not.

Answer (score 2):

I've already burned through more time than I should have on this, but while it's not a complete answer, the few major problems that I found were:

1. The hashing algorithm is SHA1, not SHA256. [as @Evk already noted]
2. `HttpServerUtility.UrlToken(De|En)code()` use a url-safe variant of base64 that needs to be replicated.

   ```
   function base64url_encode($bin) {
       return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($bin));
   }

   function base64url_decode($str) {
       return base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $str));
   }
   ```
3. When you decode the token the result is a binary string, and trying to run that through mb_convert_encoding to change the endian-ness [I found that awful blog post too] won't do what you think. You can try the following, but the token has an odd number of bytes which is problematic no matter which way you look at it. [edit: is there just a bare `\x0d` carriage return at the end?]

   ```
   function swapEndian16($in) {
       $out = '';
       foreach(str_split($in, 2) as $chunk) {
           $out .= $chunk[1] . $chunk[0];
       }
       return $out;
   }
   ```
4. The last argument to [`hash_pbkdf2()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) should be `true`, otherwise you're getting a hex-encoded hash rather than the raw bytes.

Really what I'd suggest is asking your vendor if they have any insight on accomplishing this. Chances are that someone's already had and solved this problem with their integrations.

**Edit:** With the new info from @Evk's answer, here are some sassily-named functions for compatibility with C#'s *brilliant* base64 URL encoding:

```
function dumb_base64url_encode($bin) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/(=*)$/',
        function($matches){
            return strlen($matches[0]);
        },
        str_replace(
            ['+', '/'],
            ['-', '_'],
            base64_encode($bin)
        ),
        1
    );
}

function dumb_base64url_decode($str) {
    return base64_decode(
        str_replace(
            ['-', '_'],
            ['+', '/'],
            substr($str, 0, -1)
        )
    );
}
```

So now, with the un-"corrected" token:

```
$token = "MqsXexqpYRUNAHR_lHkPRic1g1BYhH6bFNVPagEkuaL8Mf80l_tOirhThQYIbfWYErgu4bDwl-7brVhXTWnJNQ2";
$id = "bob@company.com";
$ssokey = "7MpszrQpO95p7H";
$idAndKey = $id . $ssokey;
$salt = dumb_base64url_decode($token);
$hashed = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $idAndKey, $salt, 1000, 24, true);
$data = dumb_base64url_encode($hashed);
echo $data; // output: aE1k9-djZ66WbUATqdHbWyJzskMI5ABS0
```

And don't sweat whose answer to mark correct, I think @Evk's got the most important bits sorted.

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch. This looks great. I realized that we hadn't sorted out the un-"corrected" token piece. While that isn't a very complicated task, I do appreciate the thorough-ness of your answer